# How to convert Latin characters to UTF-8 format in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, transformation

I have a XML which has some latin characters like é,ä,å,ß,ö etc and I have to transform this XML a CSV file using XSLT 2.0 and have to replace these latin characters to the UTF-8 format. I have used character-map to map these 5 characters to e,ae,aa,ss,oe respectively but the input XML can have many other characters like these. Is there a way that I can convert these characters using some encoding? Any leads would be really helpful.

Regards,
Abhi

Comment: So what exactly has the representation of `é` as `e` to do with UTF-8? If you want to create a CSV file that is UTF-8 encoded with XSLT then use `xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"` and the XSLT processor will then create a file containing the two bytes `C3A9` for that character `é`.

Comment: Can you add a small sample input and expected output?

Comment: How do you know it's not already in UTF-8? What's the xml declaration of the file (first line)?

Comment: The input XML is like below

<Tag xmlns:xx="abc">
<Tag1>
<Employee_ID>1234</wd:Employee_ID>
<LastName>Jäde</LastName>
<Address>Straße</Address>
</Tag>
</Tag>

The output that we want on the csv file is

1234,Jaede,Strasse

Comment: It seems I have phrased the question in a wrong way. The output is in UTF-8 format but what we want is to figure out a way where these latin characters are automatically converted to the english letters equivalent like é as e. I used character-map to do that but in that case I have to map every character separately so, trying to understand if there is a way to do it automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can strip accents by first converting strings to decomposed normal form (in which the accents are represented by separate codepoints), and then stripping the accents using the replace() function:

```
replace(normalize-unicode($in, 'NFD'), 
        '\p{IsCombiningDiacriticalMarks}', '')
```

That doesn't solve cases like ß and æ, but it will get you a long way.

(Also: this strips accents from accented letters. But it has nothing to do with your question title, which is about conversion to UTF-8. I suspect you are confused about the actual requirements.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use translate function by giving the mapping for corresponding:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#x00E4;&#x00DF;','&#x0061;&#x0042;')"/>
```